# Return Current User in Route (User Object doesnt get passed through)

Tags: laravel, model, routes

Basically, very simple: just a theoretical question.

```
Route::get('/', function(User $user) {
dd($user->id);
//Returns null
```

So how come, this returns null ?
i am passing through the (logged in) User object but it does not come through. Isnt this supposed to go like that? 
yeah i mean you could go and say get the Auth instance and whatsoever, but generally speaking, this should definitely pass through the user object of the current logged in user right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use App\User;


Route::get('/', function(User $user) {
 echo Auth::user($user);
});
```

**or**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function(Request $request) {
    echo $request->user();
});
```

Comment: I did not test it but Auth::user(); returns the current authenticated user object in any case. What i was looking for was a reasonable explanation as to why the passed through user Object returns null. Thanks for the effort though, the request part is interesting

Comment: if you get your answer and its helpful for you so please give upvote so other people refer this answer thank you !.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use the Request to get the user object, and with that you have full access to whatever data you need from the user object.

```
// don't forget to include
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function(Request $request) {
    dd($request->user());
});
```

From there you can use `$request->user()->id;` to get the current user id.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving The Authenticated User id

```
Route::get('/', function() {

   dd(Auth::user()->id);

   //or for laravel 5.7 or above
   dd(Auth::id()); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
if you use Auth :

```
 Route::get('/', function() {
 return Auth::user()->id
  }
```

else

```
    Route::get('/', function(User $user,$username) {
    $user = $user->where('username',$username)->first();
    return $user->id
    }
```